# Twitter tweeting error because of [ ] characters from a macOS App

Tags: ios, macos, twitter, utf-8, macos-sierra

Twitter shows error message for all tweets which has these `[` `]` characters. Error given below;

```
 HTTP Status 401: Unauthorized, Response: {"errors":
[{"code":32,"message":"Could not authenticate you."}]}
```

I have been developing a `Twitter` client in `macOS`, recently realised that if I put `[` or `]` in a tweet content, the tweet is not getting tweeted. `Twitter` just sends back the error message given above.

I am using `macOS Sierra`, I have faced the same issue in `El Capitan` and and also in `Yosemite`, but I could not reproduce the issue neither in `iOS` nor in `Android` twitter clients which I built. In `iOS` and `Android` it just works fine.

I am damn sure that I don't do any kind of string encoding before I tweet the content, I submit a normal `String` value to system's default `JSONSerialisation` method which takes care of converting it into corresponding `Data` format with anyone of the following encoding `UTF-8, UTF-16LE, UTF-16BE, UTF-32LE, UTF-32BE`.

Have you guys faced an issue like this in macOS, Thanks in advance !!

Comment: _"could not reproduce the issue neither in iOS nor in Android"_ – meaning in the official Twitter clients on these platforms?

Comment: @xoudini Updated question!!

Comment: can you inspect the payload with Fiddler or another tool and see if the corresponding JSON is valid? Perhaps the [] need to be escaped in some way.